# SSH session does not get terminated with cpp reboot command but with CLI command reboot

Tags: c++, linux, ssh, debian-based

I have a small cpp application which will reboot the system. This works very well so far.

```
sync(); //need for data safety
reboot(RB_AUTOBOOT);
```

Unless you are connected via SSH and run this program on the connected device. Then the SSH connection hangs.

If you are connected via SSH and use the CLI commands

```
sudo reboot
```

or

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

The SSH connection will be terminated with the following message

```
Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed by remote host.
Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed.
```

How do I get the same behaviour with the cpp reboot method?

I read https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/reboot.2.html and search the internet, but didn't found something about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sudo reboot` command will notify `init` that you want a reboot, init will kill all user-space processes and then do the actual kernel reboot.

The `reboot` syscall does the equivalent of `sudo reboot -f` (immediate reboot).

You could try to kill everything yourself and then invoke the syscall.

Or you could ask init, which by convention lives at PID=1. Reboot is signalled by sending it a SIGINT.

So:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main() {
    kill(1, SIGINT);
}
```

should do it.